# How to read from mp3 in chunks/buffers

Tags: audio, python

I am developing a web app that does real-time processing on audio on a server and streams the processed audio to the client.

The current implementation works using wav format, but obviously using uncompressed audio is terrible for streaming and storage requirements, so I want to do it using mp3 instead.

The server is written in python and currently works something like this:

```python
import wave

BUFFER_SIZE = 2048 # or whatever size works best

wav = wave.open("file.wav") # open the file

# code that gets called by the client when it's ready for the next buffer
    buffer = wav.readframes(BUFFER_SIZE) # read BUFFER_SIZE samples from the file
    # code that processes the buffer and sends it to the client
```

I'm having a lot of trouble finding ways to do this using mp3 or a similar compressed format. Here are options I've thought of:

**Option 1:**
Using something like ffmpeg, transcode the file to an uncompressed format such as wav and then do the processing. This is undesirable because of the storage/memory requirements. I might have a file that's 10 hours long, that's too big uncompressed.

**Option 2:**
Find a way to use a tool such as ffmpeg to read the buffers directly from the file. I can't figure out how to accomplish this. I believe there are some issues as well with trying to read a specific number of samples from a compressed file. I know that ffmpeg can read a segment of the file specified in seconds/miliseconds, but I want to specify a number of *samples*. Is this possible?

**Option 3:**
Use two levels of buffers. Read a medium-size chunk of the file into memory uncompressed, and pull the smaller processing buffers out of this larger buffer. When the remaining samples in the larger buffer is less than the smaller buffer size, read more into the larger buffer. I believe I know how to implement this using ffmpeg, but it doesn't feel like the right answer. It's not elegant.

I can't be the first person trying to accomplish this task, but I can't find anything online talking about how to do it.

Comment: How about https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ?

Comment: @Hilmar, according to the docs for pysoundfile, it does not support mp3.

from their docs: 
soundfile.available_formats()[source]

    Return a dictionary of available major formats.

    Examples

    >>> import soundfile as sf
    >>> sf.available_formats()
    {'FLAC': 'FLAC (FLAC Lossless Audio Codec)',
     'OGG': 'OGG (OGG Container format)',
     'WAV': 'WAV (Microsoft)',
     'AIFF': 'AIFF (Apple/SGI)',
     ...
     'WAVEX': 'WAVEX (Microsoft)',
     'RAW': 'RAW (header-less)',
     'MAT5': 'MAT5 (GNU Octave 2.1 / Matlab 5.0)'}

Comment: Try [moviepy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/audioclips.html). `audioclip = AudioFileClip("some_audiofile.mp3")`